I want to find all the registered EditorPlugins in Godot 4.3
I'm studying Godot and I want to learn about the tabs in the bottom panel (where we find Output, Debugger, etc). For the moment, I've seen that you can add nodes extending EditorPlugin in order to add new tabs, for example.
I'm trying to find out how does Godot handle all of its own EditorPlugins in the source code, as I'd like to add a tab similar to the ones that appear when you click on a TileMapLayer (TileSet and TileMap), so I want to check these EditorPlugins and the UIs related to them, but I can't find them in the source code.
Is it impossible to see them? If it's not, where could I find them? I'm working with GDExtension and C++.
Thanks in advance!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
